# Enable SFTP for upgrades

Tags: 8, updating, installation

After installing D8 on my server, I wanted to add some modules, so I went to *Extend* / *Install new module* and was told I needed FTP access to the server.  I've got my server configured to only use SFTP, and that's not an option in the **Connection method** drop list - only `FTP` is offered.  For initial installation, that wasn't much of a problem - I went to the PuTTY windows I have open with SSH connections to the server, wrote a script to download, extract and correctly place the modules in the Drupal directory tree.  That made the new modules available on the **Extend** page so I could mark their checkboxes to enable them.

Now there are updates, and again I'm being told I have to use FTP to upload to the server - and `FTP` is the only **Connection method** available.

I've configured my Drupal-driven site with an SSL certificate, and set it up for full-time HTTPS - any attempts to access the site as HTTP are redirected to an HTTPS connection.  Consequently, I know the site has a working SSL certificate.

What do I have to do to make **SFTP** available as a **Connection method** in the page for installing and updating modules for my site?

Comment: TBH the best way is to manage them with Composer and do deployments. Alternatively, you can use Drush on the server to do the same. I recommend either one over the built in UI as well as trying the modules on lower environment first so you don't bring down your site.

Comment: SFTP is not an option for using the admin UI to install/upgrade modules. The best way to deal with code is a combination of Composer and GIT.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the FreeBSD package site to a Composer based one, but right now I'm stuck on [a bug](https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal/issues/3) in the `Composerize Drupal` plugin that's preventing me from moving forward.